# How can I get an answer undeleted once I've edited it to conform to the guidelines?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I answered [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6794/what-actually-happens-to-ships-using-hyperdrive-in-gravity-wells) yesterday and [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10257/4025) was subsequently deleted by [DampeS8N](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51/dampes8n). Although there was not a specific reason given for the deletion, I think it might have been that the answer was so short that it did not seem constructive. I [read the FAQ section on deletion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) to familiarize myself with the guidelines.

Well, yeah, my answer probably could have been better, so I edited it to include reasoning and supporting documentation on the answer. I think it's a lot better now; at the very least I think it's constructive.

My specific question: **so now that I've edited it, how do I request it be undeleted?**

As the FAQ said, "If you wish to improve an existing answer, click edit". So now I assume that a moderator has to look at it and agree that it's now constructive. Any help would be appreciated! And my apologies if this is not the right venue or method for asking this; I'm relatively new around here and this seems to be the right place.

Comment: This is totally the right place to ask. :)

Comment: You should make a question about it on a Meta site for SciFi (http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com) to notify moderators/high-rep users about the need for review. This question serves the purpose perfectly though it was asked for a slightly different purpose

Comment: @DVK For a deleted answer that only a few people can see, Meta isn't going to do much good. I recommend flagging first, and only going to Meta if there's an actual dispute.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer, BTW. I only just got here to see it. (Busy week and weekend.) Glad Gilles could help you undelete it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your answer was deleted by a moderator. Only another moderator can undelete an answer deleted by a moderator. So if you want your answer to be undeleted because you've improved it, flag it.

Note that it would have been ok in this case to post another answer. Version 2 of your answer is so different, with references to existing material, that posting it as a separate answer would have been justified. This way you would have avoided the downvote (all votes come back with the undeletion of the answer). Hopefully the downvoter will see your revised answer and cancel the downvote.

Generally speaking, if there's something you'd like to do but you can't because you don't have the required privilege, you can flag to have a moderator do it. If it's not obvious, explain in your flag message why the moderator should oblige your request.

Comment: This answer is very helpful, I appreciate it. I see that my answer has been undeleted now. Thanks also for the tip on the downvote thing, although downvotes don't bother me a lot :)

Comment: @Gilles - is there a good summary somewhere of what privilege are required for all actions (including moderator-only)? I recall there was a table for rep requirements somewhere in my profile but can't seem to find it anymore.

Comment: @DVK For reputation privileges: [`/privileges`](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/privileges) (same list and descriptions on every site, the thresholds are different in beta), linked from the [faq]. For moderator-only actions: I don't think it's all collected in one place, search for thinngs like “moderator tools” on [metase].

Answer (score 3):

Ask in the chat room, here, or just flag it. The only people who can undelete a post are moderators or very high ranked users.

Personally, I would just flag it, saying you've fixed it, and ask to have it undeleted.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I have flagged it, we'll see what happens :)